# What is the best way to use CiviCRM for on-site registration at an event?

Tags: civievent

We have an event coming up and this is the first time we've used Civi to handle our registrations both pre-event and on-site. It is possible that we will have people attend who are not yet in our database. As I understand it the existing workflow for registering a new contact would be to add a new individual, enter their info, save the contact, click events, add event registration, pick the event, pick their options. [...]. That's a lot of different screens to jump through.

My solution for this piece was to keep the online registration open and add a menu item to a blank form. Then our folks doing registration can just  bring up the form and key in the participant's info and event options (we have a couple lunch and banquet choices they get). However, we also want to record payments. This means having a second tab open, refreshing the participant list, editing the registration, and recording the payment. Which works if your "cashier" is a different person than your data entry person.

Has anyone used Civi for on-site registrations like this? Is there something I'm missing? Absent custom coding is there a way I can build a profile or use Drupal Webform to allow a registration team member to enter a new person, select their registration options, and record a payment  all on one screen? I imagine if not, I can do it with the API and build a  page, but I'm not sure I can get it done in the time I have.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Rachel

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a Drupal-Civi webform will allow you to do just what you've described.

Note that if your event uses a price set, you will have to get creative (see below).

From [Webform CiviCRM Integration](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration):

> Event registration via webform is extremely flexible; any number of
>   contacts can be registered for any number of events on a single form.
>   If your form has multiple contacts on it, you may choose to register
>   them each separately for different events, or all together for the
>   same event(s). If you choose to register them together, CiviCRM will
>   show contact 1 as having registered the others...
>
> With payment integration, events can be paid for online or offline via
>   webforms (see notes below on supported payment processors). Note that
>   CiviCRM pricesets are not supported and fees should instead be
>   allocated using the "event fee" field provided by this module.

If you have your staff/volunteers using the webform on behalf of registrants, you can also have exposed [Existing Contact fields](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration#WebformCiviCRMIntegration-WorkingwithExistingContacts) to look up whether registrants are already in the system or not, all on the same screen.